# Cannot filter array that contains vue-mc models

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mc

I am trying to filter an array that contains vue-mc models. However the name property is always undefined for some reason.

This is what I am doing:

```
computed: {
    filtered_items:function() {
      var self=this;
      return this.local_items.filter(
        function(item) {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.user_input.toLowerCase())>=0;
        });
    }
  }
```

And it gives me the following error which makes sense because for some reason you can't access the models key like "`item.name`":

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

So the question is, how should I filter the array of vue-mc models? Or how to access the models key value? [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n975nxl42p) is also the sandbox I made.

Comment: This a typo `itemss`?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Nope, it is not typo. I can change it if it makes reading easier.

Comment: apparently item doesn't have a `name` property ? https://i.imgur.com/QLG2DzF.png

Comment: @JacobGoh In the sandbox it has title, because I use the JSONPlaceholder's api to test it.

Comment: is `filtered_items` based on `itemss` or `items`? it's `itemss` in the question but  `items` in the sandbox.

Comment: Since the `items` is prop I have to make local variable for it to be mutable. So the `filtered_items` is based on `itemss` because the itemss is basically `items`. And I am doing it  because I am passing them from parent to child component. For simplicity I changed the `itemss` to `local_items`